# How to run/install the React Native official examples?

Tags: android, react-native

For example, I'm trying to run the [UIExplorer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer) example.

1. I cloned the `https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/` repository.
2. Did `react-native init ExplorerApp`
3. Copied everything inside the `UIExplorer`folder and pasted it inside the `ExplorerApp` folder (except the `android` folder)

However, when I run `ExplorerApp` I still get "Welcome to React Native"!

Maybe I have to modify `index.android.js` so it somehow points to the pasted files? How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the official RN examples, follow [these steps](https://github.com/facebook/react-native#examples)

1. `git clone https://github.com/facebook/react-native.git`
2. `cd react-native && npm install`

**iOS**

3. Now open any example (the .xcodeproj file in each of the Examples subdirectories) and hit Run in Xcode.

**Android**

3. You need to install Android NDK : see prerequisites [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html)
4. To start the Movies Example :

> `./gradlew :Examples:Movies:android:app:installDebug`
>
> Start the packager in a separate shell (make sure you ran npm install):
>
> `./packager/packager.sh`
>
> Open the Movies app in your emulator

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to put those examples in individual folders?

Comment: They are not meant to be put in individual folders but to be tested inside the UIExplorer project itself. If you need to re-use some of these components, I suggest you copy / paste the code that suits your need inside your project.